# editing using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, string

So I have a string and I also have a regular Expression for that string. I simply want to add 8 to one of the numbers in that string. I Would like to know how I can change the value of a group and then return the match object to a string.

here is a example of what I want to do.

```
m = re.match(r"(\w+) (\w+)", "Isaac Newton, physicist")
m.group(1) = 'john'
//then some how return the value back to a string
```

so the string will be "john Newton, physicist"

Comment: whats the proper output ? for change a string with regex you must use `re.sub`

Comment: making groups writeable would be highly problematic. consider a nested grouping `(a(b))` and you do `group(0) = 'def'; group(1) = 'ghi'`. What would the final string be? By changing group(0) you've destroyed the text that matched/created group(1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), rather than `re.match`, and use the captured groups from the match in your `repl`. For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"(\w+) (\w+)", r"john \2", "Isaac Newton, physicist")
'john Newton, physicist'
```

Here `r"john \2"` means *"replace the match with the word `'john'` and the second captured group from the `pattern`"*.